# How to add file to Recent Docunents in .NET?

Tags: .net, recent-documents

I'm trying to figure out how to add a file to the recent documents using .NET. In this post [SHAddToRecentDocs doesn't add my file to recent documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577320/shaddtorecentdocs-doesnt-add-my-file-to-recent-documents) it shows how to do it via C# but how do I do it with VB.NET? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use <DllImport> in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229793/how-to-use-dllimport-in-vb-net)

Comment: There are multiple c# to vb convertors online

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! Using https://converter.telerik.com/ I was able to figure it out.

This is what I used:

```
Public Enum ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags
    Pidl = &H1
    Path = &H2
    PathW = &H3
End Enum

<DllImport("Shell32.dll", BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True)>
Private Shared Sub SHAddToRecentDocs(ByVal flag As ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags,
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal path As String)
```